# Create FOR loop inside Snowflake stored procedure to execute SQL query list from table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a loop inside a stored procedure in snowflake. I have a table created which has 3 columns (groupqueryids, query, orderid). One groupqueryids can have multiples queries and shorted by orderid. User will input the groupqueryids to execute the query set they want to execute and final query output will store the table in csv format.

I have created the query which is not working. Need help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myprocedure()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
    -- Snowflake Scripting code
    DECLARE
      count1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
      c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT query FROM qset WHERE groupquery='' ORDER BY orderid;
      res1 resultset default(SELECT query FROM qset);
      text1 VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
      FOR record IN c1 DO
        text1 := record.query;
        LET res RESULTSET := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :text1);
        -- res1 := res;
      END FOR;
      RETURN text1;
    END;
  $$
  ;

  CALL myprocedure(GQID02);
```

Comment: Your procedure doesn’t have an input parameter

Comment: @NickW even with parameter WHERE groupquery=1001 query is not working. If i remove line " LET res RESULTSET := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :text1);", its returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure works for me:

```
create or replace table t1 (groupquery varchar(10), query string, orderid int);
insert into t1 values ('GDID01', 'select * from citibike_trips limit 1', 1);
insert into t1 values ('GDID02', 'select * from citibike_trips limit 10', 2);

SELECT query FROM t1 WHERE groupquery='GDID02' ORDER BY orderid;

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myprocedure(gq varchar)
  RETURNS table()
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS
  $$
    -- Snowflake Scripting code
    DECLARE
      count1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
      res resultset DEFAULT (SELECT query FROM t1 WHERE groupquery=:gq order by orderid);
      c1 CURSOR FOR res;
      text1 VARCHAR;
      rs resultset;
    BEGIN
      FOR record IN c1 DO
        text1 := record.query;
        rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :text1);
      END FOR;
      RETURN table(rs);
    END;
  $$
  ;

  CALL myprocedure('GDID02');
```

I get back:

[image]

Comment: How to execute the output sql query?

Comment: @Big_Data_engineer I've adjusted my answer to show you can actually get the resultset of running a SQL query in the loop. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Its working fine and what i was looking for. Thank You

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can then mark the answer as correct.

Comment: How to export the output in .csv format using query to the local.

Comment: To export you need to use [COPY INTO <location>](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location) rather than only the SELECT. The SELECT will be part of the subquery as you will see in the examples provided in the documentation.